# How to make react-router's NavLink open the app intent in Android mobile browser?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-intent, react-router, deep-linking

I have a pretty standard layout of a React SPA with react-router and `<NavLink>`'s pointing to various locations in the app like this:

Somewhere in routed component:

```
  <div styleName="category">
    <NavLink
      styleName="categoryNavLink"
      to={{ pathname: "/someBaseUrl/category/someSlug" }}
      activeClassName={"active"}
      onClick={this.props.onLeave}
      ...
    >
      <span>Some category name</span>
    </NavLink>
  </div>
```

I want to make the mobile browser suggest my app as handler for `https://.../someBaseUrl/category/someSlug` URI using the filter/intent feature.

The android developer who I'm working with is having a problem making the browser respect the intent when using deep-linking feature. They can't make the links declared in NavLink suggest the native application as link handler

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Have you encountered this problem? Is `react-router` and, more generally, HTML5 History API supposed to work with Android deep linking without problems?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you/your developer find a solution? So If I'm not mistaken, you're adding intents to all links in your webapp using `react-router` so that when clicked on mobile, it'll suggest your native app?